# Add Index to Date String field in MySql

Tags: mysql, string, date

I have a table with approximately 2mn records. It has a column with date values in `String` format (similar format). Now I need to filter records based on this string date column. I tried with `STR_TO_DATE` but it takes ages to fetch records as this column doesn't have an `INDEX`.
Can anyone help me adding an `Index` to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping a column in function in a predicate forces MySQL to evaluate the function on every row, effectively disabling a potentially more efficient index seek or range scan.

As an example, MySQL can't use an index range scan with this

```
... FROM t WHERE STR_TO_DATE(t.mycol,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2018-04-23'
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but having the SQL reference a bare column would allow MySQL to consider using a range scan operation on an appropriate index ...

```
... FROM t WHERE t.mycol = DATE_FORMAT('2018-04-23','%Y-%m-%d') 
                 ^^^^^^^
```

A first cut at an suitable index for the latter query would be

```
   CREATE INDEX t_IX1 ON t (mycol)
```

This isn't necessarily the best index for the query. It really depends on the query. For example, a covering index might be a more suitable choice.

---

The question mentions storing "date" values as strings, presumably meaning CHAR or VARCHAR datatype. Note that MySQL implements a native `DATE` datatype, which is custom designed for storing "date" values.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and really sorry for late reply, I fixed this problem by adding a column with datatype `DATETIME` and a `after` `insert` `trigger` (my table doesn't have update) to update the newly added column reading the value from `VARCHAR` type date.

Comment: Note that a BEFORE INSERT trigger could simply assign a value to the newly added column, e.g. `SET NEW.newly_added_col = ... ;` That would be more efficient than an AFTER INSERT trigger.

Comment: Thank you so much, that actually makes sense.